# Flutter: Add location permission on IOS in permission handler

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, permissions

I have a web view on my flutter project. Inside web view widget i am checking location permission with permission handler like below:

```
  void _checkLocationPermission() async {
    if (await Permission.location.request().isGranted) {
      Position position = await getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
      if (position == null) {
        latitude = "";
        longitude = "";
      } else {
        latitude = position.latitude.toString();
        longitude = position.longitude.toString();
      }
      setState(() {
        isPermission = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

In Info.plist i added these permissions:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Needed to access location</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Needed to access location</string>
```

And this is podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

#post_install do |installer|
#  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
#    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
#  end
#end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
        'PERMISSION_LOCATION=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
        'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=0'
        ]
    end
  end
end
```

I commented default post install :

```
#post_install do |installer|
#  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
#    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
#  end
#end
```

and I added these lines at the end of this file, according permission handler [suggestion](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler):

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
        'PERMISSION_LOCATION=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
        'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=0'
        ]
    end
  end
end
```

But when i run on my iphone 7 plus when i open my web view the permission request dialog not shown and i don't have location permission!!!

podfile is correct? Because this is a first time i added something in podfile!!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need permission handler for this,this feature is available with `Location plugin` checkout their official

**Download and import plugin**

[location](https://pub.dev/packages/location)

**Add Permission**

iOS
And to use it in iOS, you have to add this permission in Info.plist :

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

For more info checkout [official plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/location)

**Initialize variables**

```
  String latitude_data;
  String longitude_data;
  bool _serviceEnabled;
```

**Current Location Function**

```
 Future _getLocation() async {
         
            Location location = new Location();
        
            var _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
            _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
        
            if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted || !_serviceEnabled) {
///asks permission and enable location dialogs
              _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
        
              _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
        
            
            } else {
            ///Do something here
            }
        
            LocationData _currentPosition = await location.getLocation();
        
            longitude_data=_currentPosition.longitude.toString();
            latitude_data=_currentPosition.latitude.toString();
        
        ///if you want you can save data to sharedPrefrence   
         SharedPrefrence().setLatitude(_currentPosition.latitude.toString());
            SharedPrefrence().setLongitude(_currentPosition.longitude.toString());
        
          
          
          }
```

Then uninstall the app from phone,run flutter clean and run again

Comment: Yes, I found out that geolocator don't need to permission handler. Thanks Anyway.

Comment: It didn't work on web unfortunately https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64411270/flutter-web-get-location-on-web-by-location-plugin @Assassin

Comment: for setup location in web follow this https://dev.to/aseemwangoo/flutter-web-and-location-2l1@sayreskabir

Comment: At the end of my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64411270/flutter-web-get-location-on-web-by-location-plugin , I mentioned that i use Mozilla location, but it is not work too @Assassin

Answer (score 0):

Actually you added the values in Podfile backwards.
You need to assign them "1" for them to be allowed. Now you have actually denied them:
'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',
'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1'